# Objective-C : Dynamic message in info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, info-plist

Can I change the camera access permission info.plist message dynamically in Objective-C, because I need to show some dynamic values in message from API response.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.
But I met with custom info popups before system popups.
Other solution would be to have Info.plist localized in multiple languages and then before showing system popup just force localisation based on which text you want to display.(I didn't test this) 
BTW why would you wanna do that?

Comment: In my application user can login from different company, so for display the permission message with company name. Ex :- "XYZ uses camera to upload a photos to album."

Comment: XYZ should be the name of your application in that case. Even if you will achieve this, I don't think you'll pass Apple review process. They are pretty strict about the permissions.